# String concatenation in NATS server config

Tags: configuration, nats.io

Can I make a concatenation of  **variables** and **strings** in NATS configuration file. For instance:

```
authorization {

  VERSION = "v1"

  REQUSTOR = {
    publish = ["msg." + $VERSION + ".bazz", "msg." + $VERSION + ".spam"]
    subscribe = "inbox." + $VERSION
  }

  users = [
     {
       user: foo,
       password: bar,
       permissions: $REQUSTOR
     }
  ]

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No this is not possible. I have even tried with `"msg.$VERSION.bazz"`, but then it does not replace with the variable value and uses the string as-is.